# UIAlertView button title goes white in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uialertview

I am working a old application which have lots of alert view. This application working fine in iOS7 but in iOS8 Alert view buttons text color goes white and it is not visible. Functionality wise it is working in iOS8 too.
Please see the screen shot for more understanding.
[image]

Comment: Are you customizing the UIAlerView’s buttons ?

Comment: no.. its standard UIAlertView.

Comment: Can you paste code here ?

Comment: UIAlert View has been deprecated from IOS 8. Please go through this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Comment: can we have any quick fix for Text Color? Changing all UIAlertView to UIAlerController is too time consuming process. I am looking for simple solution.

Comment: Please search in the project for the following text "[UIAlertView appearance]". If you will find it then remove that line. It doesn't make any change on iOS 7 and looks like it may change the color in iOS8

Comment: @Szu, I have checked for [UIAlertView appearance] and i am sure i have not set appearance for UIAlerView.

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Comment: Also check for UIButton appearance in your project

Answer (score 1):

You Try This Code

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alrt" message:@"This is the Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                       }];

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"OK action");
                                   }];

        [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
        [alertController addAction:okAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

[image]

Comment: But it is available from iOS8.

Comment: I am aware with UIAlertController but i want to only Text Color issue. this issue happen only in iOS8.

Comment: can we have any quick fix for Text Color? Changing all UIAlertView to UIAlerController is too time consuming process. I am looking for simple solution.